# Is APITest with Query params different then just normal url?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm writing some unit tests against an API that either returns all the books, or only returns the books of the given genre in the query params. This seems to be working when I hit it in my local dev server. However, it doesn't even go into the else statement if the genre is specified in my unit test.

My unit test looks like this:

```
class TitlesAndBlurbsListTestCase(APITestCase):
     def setUp(self):
     # Creates a lot of books with genre horror
     # and books not in the horror genre

     def test_horror_genre(self):
         # Ensure that screener can see all the available books
         self.client.login(username='b', password='b')
         response = self.client.get('/api/titles-and-blurbs/?genre=horror')
         self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

         # Ensure that the screener gets all horror books at first
         horror_books = TitlesAndBlurbs.objects.filter(genre='horror')
         # I keep getting an assertion error here - it returns all the books
         self.assertEqual(len(response.data), horror_books.count())
```

My api viewset looks like this

```
class TitlesAndBlurbsListViewSet(viewsets.mixins.ListModelMixin,
               viewsets.mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    model = TitlesAndBlurbs
    permission_classes = [ScreenerPermissions]
    serializer_class = TitlesAndBlurbsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            genre = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('genre', None)
            if not genre:
                print 'i dont have query params of genre'
                TitlesAndBlurbs.objects.all()
            else:
                print genre
                TitlesAndBlurbs.objects.filter(genre=genre)
        return TitlesAndBlurbs.objects.all()
```

my url/router looks like

```
router.register(r'api/titles-and-blurbs', TitlesAndBlurbsListViewSet)
```

When I hit the url 'api/titles-and-blurbs/?genre=horror' in my browser I get the print statement and titles and blurbs that have the genre horror. However, when I hit in the
test suite, I don't get the print statement genre I get the print statement of 'i dont have query params', and it returns all books. Any help is really
appreciated.

Comment: Just to test where it's going wrong, would you change your view code a bit? Change it so `if not genre` returns something different than what you get if `self.action == 'list'` is not True. Basically, I'd like to see at *which* point it's breaking: whether the action is not list or whether it's not getting a genre. You can change it back after you find that.

Comment: It gets into the self.action == 'list' - I know it is because there is another if statement the action that i'm not displaying because it's not relevant.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try passing the query parameter as a data payload instead. Change the line in your test to:

```
response = self.client.get('/api/titles-and-blurbs/', {'genre': 'horror'})
```

Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) on the different ways to pass query parameters in urls.

Another person reported a similar issue with an empty `QUERY_PARAMS` while testing DRF (see [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1461)). It looks like they fixed it but maybe they missed something or you didn't get the update.

Comment: That was it. Very strange. I'm on Django==1.6.2 djangorestframework==2.3.13

Comment: @user2734679 Yep, looking at PyPi, it looks like they haven't released a new package since the update.

Comment: Wonderfull, appreciated for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across this, for me it helped to:to change the url from

`/api/titles-and-blurbs?genre=horror`
to

`/api/titles-and-blurbs/?genre=horror`

Both urls were working find in Postman, but only the second one is working properly in the tests.

Comment: I think in this case it's because Postman follows redirects whereas the test client doesn't. By default, Django redirects when the trailing slash is omitted and sends you to the "correct" url (the one including the trailing slash).